# Creating New Xcode Project Based On Existing Files. (Creating Laps into an NSTimer)

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer

I am new to Xcode, and I have already created an NSTimer for an iOS Application which works, but I really need to extend this App with a Laptimer, I have found a really good Code of a Laptimer, and downloaded the Source Code, but as it is no project, just files
I do not know how to merge the .h, .m and the .xib file into one new project, that everything works properly.

Comment: What files are we dealing with here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open your project and [choose "add files" from the "file" menu](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/adding_an_existing_file.html) (or drag and drop from finder). I'd suggest choosing the option to copy them to your folder, and make sure you have a checkmark next to your project as you're adding the files.

Unfortunately, the process of integrating this new code into your app is a non-trivial exercise and depends entirely upon the particulars of your project, and on the code you're adding to your project.

For example, copying .h and .m files (if the names are unique), is easy. But does your project use NIBs or Storyboards? How about the code you're copying in? How are you going to integrate the user interface files. It's non-trivial and it's hard for us to answer in the abstract.

---

If you want to create a new project for your `LapTimer.xib`, `LapTimerController.h`, `LapTimerController.m`, `UIButton.h`, and `UIButton.m` files, you can:

1. Create a new project using the "Single View Application" template (make sure to choose not to use storyboards, but you probably want to use automatic reference counting);
2. Add the five files above to your project (make sure you choose "copy items" to destination folder, as well as have a checkmark next to your app's "target");
3. Then, presumably, change your `AppDelegate.m` so that the `#import` line that says

   ```
   #import "ViewController.h"
   ```

   should be changed to says

   ```
   #import "LapTimerController.h"
   ```

   Likewise, the line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` that says:

   ```
   self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
   ```

   should say:

   ```
   self.viewController = [[LapTimerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LapTimer" bundle:nil];
   ```
4. Try building the app and pray.

Comment: Well I already tried to integrate all the code into my project. What I want to know is how is it possible to create a new xCode project with existing .m and .h and .xib files.. I tried to create a new one, adding all the files, does not work at all.. and to a single-view app, but mostly it does not work. 

the file structure of the existing files looks like this:
LapTimer.xib
LapTimerController.h
LapTimerController.m
UIButton.h  
UIButton.m

Comment: @dev.geek see revised answer that outlines the process a bit. If this doesn't work, please share a link to your LapTimer code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @dev.geek: Note that you can "accept" a helpful answer by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved and gives some reputation points to you and to the auther of the answer.

Comment: Thanks ! I am new to Stack ; did not know :)